Equivalent to InternetSetCookieEx for Edge Browsers
I've inherited some legacy code that was using InternetSetCookieEx to add cookies that were being picked up by the Windows WebBrowser control which is IE based. I'm planning on moving to using the WebView2 control and after some testing it's obvious the cookies are not being picked up in the new Control.  Does anyone know is there an equivalent that will allow me to add the cookies.  The current code is not adding the cookies to instance of the Control, but is adding to the general cookies available to IE and therefore multiple instances of the control in different applications are able to to see the shared cookies.

You need to call CoreWebView2CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie to add a cookie. The cookies are shared by all WebView2 instances that use the same profile. There is no global cookie manager.
